# Protecting Tires from House Cats

Tags: tire, damage

I have a friend with several cats, one of which destroyed the material of their bike tires and is presumed to enjoy doing so.. having acquired new tires and tubes (but not yet put them on), how can we prevent the cat from chewing/scratching the new pair?

We had thought

- bag the tires (no good; likely too thin and they love bags too)
- move the bike outside (no, it will definitely be stolen)
- spray the tires with lime juice, vinegar, etc. which the cat will find unpleasant (this at least works for ferrets which love chewing cables)
- decoy tires (see: cats on keyboards)
- some sort of removable, thick rubber coating (perhaps a second, larger pair of tires cut to fit over mounting)
- hard case for bike (probably too expensive)

Other details

- bike is a Schwinn road bike without fenders
- no garage is available and it is impractical to store at my place
- the cats are otherwise delightful
- bike will be left unattended indoors for long periods of time (weekends/workday..)
- open to trading in the bike and getting something heftier if that's the only solution

Likely also suitable for [Pets StackExchange](https://pets.stackexchange.com/), but I doubt this is an unheard-of problem in this community

Comment: What about suspending them from the ceiling or a wall, the bikes obviously! ;-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fundamentally about stopping cats damaging things. The fact that the damaged things are bike tires is incidental. Should be migrated to pets.se.

Comment: @Carel Cheers, that could be a good and obvious solution! I suspect a stand would be wanted to prevent apartment damage, but I'll find out.

Comment: Have you considered a good u-lock when storing the bike outside? The smaller the u-lock the better (harder to put a hydraulic jack in). My favorite is Kryptonite Evolution Mini-5. With a good lock, the bicycle frame will never be stolen (although if you live in a high-risk area, the parts can be stolen from the locked bike).

Comment: @juhist Yes, any bike left unattended will be stolen or vandalized beyond use

Comment: You could always declaw the cats.

Comment: @DanielRHicks while now this is *really* a topic more suitable for the pets SE, I believe vets and owners in the US are increasingly accepting that declawing is not best practice, as it's very traumatic for cats. There are almost surely behavioral solutions available for the OP anyway.

Comment: Furthering that, I believe they actually chew at tires rather than clawing, though they probably do both, especially if they like the feeling. For those unfamiliar with the ethical debate, traditional de-clawing removes the terminal digit of the cat's fingers/toes. Cats do not like this.

Comment: @WeiwenNg - You can simply use a nail trimmer to cut the claws down to where they can't "grab" anything.

Comment: If no cat-free room is available, you may be able to cover the bike with some thick fabric or canvas. Like the kind of fabric used for suitcases or outdoor furniture. Otherwise a cardboard box or a box made out of thin plywood or masonite. The idea of hanging them from a ceiling may work too.

Comment: I would be worried about cats touching the chain and then ingesting dirty lubricant too. My choice would be to somehow make the bike inaccessible.

Comment: @DanielRHicks *use a nail trimmer to cut the claws*  Simply?!?!? To an older cat not used it?  That'll be all kinds of fun.  Please video it and post it to YouTube.

Comment: A pets-answer would be to give the cats a scratching post.

Comment: Another idea is a zapper.  Had a cat that liked to climb in our Christmas tree.  One Christmas season humidity was low and when one walked around on the carpet a lot of static would collect on your body.  I was in HS and had a hint of cruelty, I suppose, so I carried our cat into the room with the tree and held his head out so that a bit of tinsel would jump out and zap his nose.  Did this maybe 4 times.  The next year I was carrying the cat around, not even thinking of the tree.  When I walked into the room with the tree he took one look, leapt out of my arms, and ran out off the room.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about a bike cover or bicycle wheel covers ?

This seems the most logical form of protection for little outlay, the most effective method would be to move the bike out of reach of the cats but if that’s not possible then a cover of some sort may suffice.

[image: Bike Cover]

If the cover isn’t suitable or the cats destroy it, you could easily make a bike stand from some 6mm mdf, make it wide enough to stand the bike in but tall enough to cover the wheels

If I was on a PC i would draw up a quick image / diagram of a simple stand.

If you have hydraulic brakes do not stand your bike upside down.

Comment: The cats will shred that in an instant.

Comment: I'm getting a very Madonna vibe from the middle one !

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea "some sort of removable, thick rubber coating (perhaps a second, larger pair of tires cut to fit over mounting)" would probably work.
I would store the bike upside down and use old mountain bike tires.
If that fails, perhaps try inexpensive hard plastic tubing used for underground sprinkler systems, about 1.5 inch diameter. With luck the hardware store will split it for you lengthwise with tin shears.

Answer (score 1):

Do the cats do it while people are around?   Then a spray bottle of water can be used to deter them at the instant they start.  Yes, its slightly mean to the cats, but once they learn then the problem goes away.

Or store the bikes in a room with a closed door, keep the door closed.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no cat-free room, but I'll find out if it's to be expected while present! Most pets do seem to understand being punished for wrongdoing and will behave in such a regard unless agitated (where some cleverly misbehave for attention!), though a hands-off approach where some seemingly input-less fate befalls them (such as a surface being covered in tape aluminum foil or loose strips of tape) seems to build memory and response better than active punishment (likely something about assigning blame to a figure or the environment).